# Multivariate Gaussian, rearranging means

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis

Looking through the [the matrix cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=3274), a collection of matrix identities, I came across this one called "rearranging means" in the multivariate Normal distribution (Sec. 8.1.5 or Eq. #356, also 357):

$$N_{\mathbf{Ax}}[\mathbf{m}, \mathbf{\Sigma}] = \frac{\sqrt{det(2 \pi(\mathbf{A^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{A}} )^{-1})}}{\sqrt{det(2 \pi \mathbf{\Sigma})}} N_{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{m}, (\mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{A})^{-1} )$$

I haven't been able to find this identity in any other source.  From looking at it, it looks like it equates a distribution to itself post a linear transformation defined by $\mathbf{A}$.  Can anyone verify this thought?  It would seem to imply that in some situations it may perhaps be easier to compute a mvnpdf after some arbitrary transformation into a lower dimensional space. Could someone point me to a reference with more information on this identity?  Sorry I know this question is a bit vague.

Comment: Section 8.1.5 seems to contain eqs. 356-357, not 334.

Comment: My bad! I have an older version than the one I linked to.  Fixed

Comment: Since $A$ is explicitly invertible, this is nothing other than the (usual) formula for the change of variables $x\to Ax$.

Comment: In the part where A is not required to be invertible, it should say  [Aᵀ Σ⁻¹ A]⁻¹ Aᵀ Σ⁻¹  instead of
A⁻¹.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any references for the general identity with arbitrary $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{Q\times D}$, specially when $\text{rank}(\mathbf{A})<\min(Q,D)$. However, if we assume that $\text{rank}(\mathbf{A})=D$, then we can derive a similar identity.

Since $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is full rank, then $\text{rank}(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{A}) = D$, so $(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} \mathbf{A})^{-1}$ is well defined. Then, the quadratic term of $N_{\mathbf{x}}$ would be something like:
$$\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\mu})^T(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} \mathbf{A})(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\mu})\right]$$
By moving the $\mathbf{A}$ term to inside the brackets, we arrive at:
$$\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\mu})^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\mu})\right]$$
Which is almost $N_{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}}$, meaning that $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\mu} = \mathbf{m}$. We can use this equation figure out what $\mathbf{\mu}$ is:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\mu} &= \mathbf{m}\\
\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\mu} &= \mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{m}\\
\left[\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}\right]^{-1}\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\mu} &= \left[\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}\right]^{-1}\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{m}\\
\mathbf{\mu} &= \left[\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}\right]^{-1}\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{m}\\
\end{align}

Therefore, the correct formula for non-invertible but full column rank $\mathbf{A}$ should be:
$$N_{\mathbf{Ax}}[\mathbf{m}, \mathbf{\Sigma}] = \frac{\sqrt{\det(2 \pi(\mathbf{A^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{A}} )^{-1})}}{\sqrt{\det(2 \pi \mathbf{\Sigma})}} N_{\mathbf{x}}(\left[\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}\right]^{-1}\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{m}, (\mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{A})^{-1} )$$

Comment: As pointed out in the comments, this is a one-liner.  The appearances of "$2\pi$" are superfluous -- they cancel -- and you are left with a version of the standard formula for a change of variables.  You are correct to argue that the transformation must be invertible.  Otherwise the formula is either nonsensical or, if you try to make sense of it with singular densities, it appears to be wrong.